# DELETE RETURNING in postgres: Would the rows returned reflect the final state of the DB?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I have an application, where I have two different threads trying to access the some row in a table 'A_tbl' in postgres as follows:

Thread 1: Delete some row and return the column "***task_id***" in it 
Thread 2: Update column '***task_id***' in some row

So the queries are like

- Thread 1: DELETE from A_tbl where report_id = X RETURNING ***task_id***
- Thread 2: UPDATE A_tbl set ***task_id*** = Y WHERE report_id = Z

Lets say both threads are trying to delete/edit the same row (so X is same as Z in above queries). In that case, would the Thread 1 return me the final existing value of ***task_id***, just before deletion?

I fear that due to concurrency, the delete may see something before it starts executing, and may return that instead. So I believe that update may execute before deletion's processing happens, and after that, delete's processing happens, and returns what it saw earlier. Something like this:

1. DELETE command fired
2. UPDATE command fired
3. DELETE sees task_id 40
4. UPDATE updates task_id 50
5. DELETE removes the row
6. DELETE RETURNS task_id 40

Am I worrying too much?

Comment: You are worrying too much. If the update succeeds, then the delete transaction will see the new task_id (50). Assuming the default isolation level. If the delete transaction returns 40, then the update transaction will fail.

Comment: And you can always test. Open 2 sessions and manually try the 6 steps.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube for your response. However, manually trying out 6 steps is not possible, because I could only perform first 2 steps, the steps 3-6 are not in my control. Can you provide link to some documentation which confirms your point of view?

Comment: You can change steps 1 and 2 with `begin transaction;` and steps 5 and 6 with `commit;` and see what happens. Try the sequence above and the sequence 1-2-4-3-6-5

Comment: You can also pay around with the various isolation levels by beginning your transactions with `BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` (and any of the other levels). You'll see that you'll get different errors. See the docs for [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-begin.html)

Comment: Yes I am aware of isolation levels. I just wanted to know if in default isolation level, this should be a cause of worry?